# Blogdown site pages do not render properly

Tags: r, blogdown

I'm using RSTudio Blogdown/Github/Netlify to maintain my blog site. I'm using the Acadmic theme. When I push the changed .RMD files to Github the changed pages do not seem to deploy but if I build the entire site and push it then the site deploys on Netlify without any problem. Unfortunately, it takes about three minutes to build the entire site, so I'm looking for a faster solution.

I think that I should be able to build a single directory, which would be super fast, but when I build a directory with this, `blogdown::build_dir("content/project/cont_imp")`, the HTML document does not build properly. It seems to render as a single long javascript and since all of the metadata in the YAML header is wrapped into the script the page on Netlify does not deploy properly, things like the date and subtitle are missing and it is not formatted like the rest of my site.

I have one bad page that I built with `build_dir` on GitHub so you can view both the .RMD source and .HTML rendered documents: https://github.com/grself/icochise/tree/master/content/project/cont_imp. You can see this project page on my live site at: https://icochise.com/ (scroll down to the "Projects" section and notice the difference between the "Continuous Improvement" link (no text there, just an image of a hand and a whiteboard) and the "Blogdown and Bookdown" link. I just now noticed that the HTML document seems to be some sort of self-extracting javascript so after a couple of seconds the source code looks normal. Maybe there is some kind of setting on Netlify I need to change so it will extract the javascript as it is deploying the page?

I checked the settings in my "Configure Build Tools" and unchecked "Preview site after building" and "Re-knit current preview..." but that didn't help. I also tried changing the Project build tools dropdown from "Website" to "Custom" and specified the Hugo executable. None of these things helped.

I also tried running "Serve Site" while I worked, thinking that would continuously render the HTML page, but that tool seemed to hang and would not display the site once I made changes to an .RMD file. In fact, it was hung up so badly that I had to kill RStudio with the Windows Task Manager.

Finally, I also tried to update Hugo, hoping that there was something fouled up in my Hugo install, but that did not help.

I suspect that I'm doing some simple thing wrong, but have tried everything I can think of to fix this and would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I just now started the "serve site" server and accessed a new post. I worked on that post for a few minutes (added some trivial content), then stopped the server and took a look at the generated index.html page, it is correct and is not self-contained. It looks like just running the "serve site" server while I'm working on a post will generate a proper HTML document, so I have a work-around.

Comment: I've checked the help files and it looks like the default setting for gitbook output is self-contained=FALSE but default for html_document is self-contained=TRUE. The help file states that gitbook passes its arguments to html_document but it seems like that is not happening on my computer for some reason. How would I check that? Can I add a directive to the TOML configuration file or even a document's YAML header to force self-contained to be FALSE?

Comment: For the record (due to cross-posting): https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/339

Comment: I appreciate the information provided by tcgriffith and yihui on the github issues site. They answered my question and gave me a path forward.